# Animating a 2d histogram with colorbar

Tags: animation, histogram, colorbar

I am trying to build a movie out of images produced with hist2d, including a colorbar. I have managed to get it to work, but not with a colorbar.

The following works (without a colorbar), where new data is produced at each iteration snap in the loop

```
    fbx=10
    fby=8
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(fbx,fby))
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    cmap='plasma'
    W_s = 350
    bins_s = 100
    bdim_s = 2.*W_s/bins_s
    ims = []

    for snap in range(n_snaps):
        histo, xedges, yedges, image = ax.hist2d(x, y, range = [[-W_s,W_s],[-W_s,W_s]], bins = bins_s, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(vmin=1e+06, vmax=3e+8), weights=(starmass*Munit)*bdim_s**-2, cmap=cmap)

        ims.append((image, ax.scatter(bh1_x, bh1_y, marker='o', facecolors='k', edgecolors='k', s=30),))

    im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=10000, repeat_delay=1000, blit=True)
im_ani.save('movie.mp4', writer=writer)
```

However, if I add a colorbar

```
ims.append((image, plt.colorbar, ax.scatter(bh1_x, bh1_y, marker='o', facecolors='k', edgecolors='k', s=30),))
```

I get the following error:
raise RuntimeError('No mappable was found to use for colorbar '
RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).